# How to submit a job with a directory of configure files in hadoop mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have a question: I want to submit a job with a directory of configure files and the directory is not in the hadoop dfs, does hadoop has some option to do this? I want to submit the directory like submit the jar file of job so that hadoop can distribute the job and the configuration directory to all datanode. I found that the -files option seems do not work when I use this command： bin/hadoop jar job.jar input output -files conf_dir. It seems that the -files option only works in hadoop streaming

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I want to submit a job with a directory of configure files and the directory is not in the hadoop dfs, does hadoop has some option to do this?

Use the [--config](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/commands_manual.html#Overview) option to specify the directory of the configuration files.

> I want to submit the directory like submit the jar file of job so that hadoop can distribute the job and the configuration directory to all datanode.

Before the job is submitted the configuration files should be present in all the nodes for the daemons to start, so it doesn't make sense to distribute them while submitting the job. For sending any additional parameters use the [-D option](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/commands_manual.html#Generic+Options). If the sidedata is huge then use [DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.205.0/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache) to distribute the data and read it in the mapper and the reducer.

> I found that the -files option seems do not work when I use this command： bin/hadoop jar job.jar input output -files conf_dir. It seems that the -files option only works in hadoop streaming.

The `-files` option takes comma separated list of **any** files (not directory) and the files are distributed to all the nodes. The framework doesn't read those file, the code in the map and reduce tasks has to explicitly read the files.

Also, according to the [Hadoop - The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010388.do)

> Be aware that some properties have no effect when set in the client configuration. For
>   example, if in your job submission you set mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum with
>   the expectation that it would change the number of task slots for the tasktrackers run-
>   ning your job, then you would be disappointed, since this property only is only honored
>   if set in the tasktracker’s mapred-site.html file. In general, you can tell the component
>   where a property should be set by its name, so the fact that mapred.task
>   tracker.map.tasks.maximum starts with mapred.tasktracker gives you a clue that it can
>   be set only for the tasktracker daemon. This is not a hard and fast rule, however, so in
>   some cases you may need to resort to trial and error, or even reading the source.